# 'Generate' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in interface 'IClientTokenGateway'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I have created BrainTreeGateway Object with following configuration.

```
Dim objBtGateway As BraintreeGateway = New BraintreeGateway()
With objBtGateway
     .Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX
     .MerchantId = "mymerchantid"
     .PublicKey = "mypublickey"
     .PrivateKey = "myprivatekey"
End With
```

after this i tried to generate client token with following statement.

```
Dim clientToken As String = objBtGateway.ClientToken.Generate()
```

This statement says "'Generate' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in interface 'IClientTokenGateway'".

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3660954/341762